# how to pass form object to html and use each item in the object in django

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have a class called user form (UserMyProfilePersonalForm)

```
    class UserMyProfilePersonalForm(forms.ModelForm):
        username = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput, max_length=50)
        first_name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput, max_length=100)
        last_name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput, max_length=100)
        email = forms.CharField(widget=forms.EmailInput, disabled=True)
        dob = forms.CharField(widget=forms.DateInput, required=True)
        profile_pic = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput)

        def __str__(self):
            return f"{self.username},{self.first_name}, {self.last_name},{self.email},{self.dob}, self.profile_pic}"

    class Meta():
        model = UserMyProfilePersonal
        fields = ("email", )
```

then in my view file, I created an object of this class

```
    newUserMyProfilePersonalForm = UserMyProfilePersonalForm.from_json(user_detail)
    print(newUserMyProfilePersonalForm.email)
    context_data = {"newUserMyProfilePersonalForm": newUserMyProfilePersonalForm}
    return render(request, "home.html", context_data)
```

Now I don't know how to fetch the data in the HTML. I tried multiple things
1. below code prints all the value as dummyusername,fname, lname,email@gmail.com,10/05/1990... this output looks the same as **str** function

```
{{newUserMyProfilePersonalForm}}
```

2. I tried `{{newUserMyProfilePersonalForm.as_p}}` but this prints all the items as a form with textbox and label but without any value in the textbox.

I want to have a textbox with values as user data e.g. email, username because I want to create "EDIT PRofile" section.

Comment: Few questions: 1. `UserMyProfilePersonalForm` is a `ModelForm`. You do not need to define all fields again. Can these repeated definitions be removed? 2. You have included only `email` field in `fields`. 3. Why are you parsing form data as JSON? [Handling a form is pretty standard in Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/#the-view).

Comment: my ModelForm is basically empty, I am not using it. I get data via webservices in a json format therefore I create the `UserMyProfilePersonalForm ` object using JSON.

The from object is created using the json and as i mention, I do get data in the data in HTML but not the way I want. I would like to have a form file e.g. email that has data from this object already filled.

Comment: Can you describe/add the data you get from web-service in the question?

Answer (score 0):

so after 2 days of effort and reading through the documentations I figured it out.
The answer as mostly is very simple.

The form `newUserMyProfilePersonalForm = UserMyProfilePersonalForm.from_json(user_detail)` was actualy not valid. 
I ran `newUserMyProfilePersonalForm.is_valid()` and this gave `False` as an output.

When the form is invalid, it cannot be rendered as html items because the way I was using it.

Below is a standard way of doing it.

```
if request.method = "POST":
    obj = userform(request.POST)
    if obj.is_valid():
        <do something with it>
    else:
        <return the invalid form to the user to show the errors>

else:
    obj = userform()
   <return this blank obj form to user so that whe can fill it>
```

thats it. its that simple.